# Is there anyway to use a public/index.html for non-logged in users, but then home#index for logged in - in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So when a visitor goes to `/` and they are NOT logged in, they get sent to `public/index.html`.

But when a visitor is logged in and they go to `/` they get sent to `home#index` i.e. `home` controller, `index` action.

There anyway to do that without converting public/index.html to an erb file or to be a view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file called `index.html` in your public folder is always going to override your routing.

You could however rename `index.html`, point `root` to your `home` controller, and in the controller just do a `redirect_to '/new_name.html'` if the user isn't logged in.

Edit:

Since the asker was using devise and filtering all actions in his home controller, this second redirect wasn't working. The authorization filters were sending him to the sign in page (this is the default action when permission is denied).

We solved this be not filtering the `index` action and thus clearing the way for our own redirect:

```
# home controller
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]
before_filter :redirect_to_marketing
# stuff
private
def
  unless user_signed_in?
    redirect_to '/marketing.html'
  end
end
```

Comment: This is almost a perfect solution. The issue now is, what happens when the user goes directly to `/` but is not logged in ? If they go to `home#index` and are not logged in, it can redirect them to `new_name.html` with no problems. But what happens when they go to the root without being logged in ? Which controller would I put that exception in or how would I handle that ?

Comment: You should check out Srdjan Pejic's answer, that would be the best long term strategy (i.e. using conditional partials). But anyway: if you point root to `home#index` (`root :to => 'home#index'` in routes.rb)and remove index.html, you would already be sending all users automatically to `home#index` when they go to `/`. Then you can check for authorization with a `before_filter` and redirect to the desired page if it fails.

Comment: Jesper, I think you are almost there you know. I have all of what you have said, in terms of the route.rb. My home controller also looks like this: https://gist.github.com/868428  This doesn't work though. Thoughts ?

Comment: It all seems kosher to me, what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error. What's happening is when I go to `/` it redirects me to `users/login`, and not `marketing.html` when I am not logged in. That's the main issue. Here is my log: https://gist.github.com/868493

Comment: Could it be that `filter_access_to :all` is also doing somekind of redirect? It feels kind of fishy, because redirects would normally show up explicitly in the log.

Comment: So what should I do with the `filter_access_to` ? Change it to what ?

Comment: That depends on what you want. Right now, the default `permission_denied` method is called ([link](http://www.tzi.org/~sbartsch/declarative_authorization/master/classes/Authorization/AuthorizationInController/ClassMethods.html)). It redirects to `/` if ´redirect_to :back` fails. You could do you the desired redirect by defining your own `permission_denied` method or by not filtering the `home#index` action and using the solution that we discussed earlier. Right now you're doing two things at once.

Comment: Great...now it works. So what I did was the following...you can actually update your answer with what I did and I will mark it as correct. What I did was in my `home` controller, I did the following: `before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]` Then, I did `before_filter :redirect_to_marketing` and `filter_access_to :show`, then in my `redirect_to_marketing` method I did: `private
    
 def redirect_to_marketing
  unless user_signed_in?
    redirect_to '/marketing.html'  
  end  
 end`

Answer (score 1):

**public/index.html** will override any root route. So, it's probably impossible to do what you need.

I suggest you extract common parts of the root page and make any functionality that depends on the login state into partials which you can load conditionally.

Comment: Well...this is what I am trying to do...I have a marketing portion of my site. If a user is not logged in, I want them to see the marketing stuff (which are all static htmls in the public directory). But, I have a login page from my main marketing site at `mydomain.com`, so if they login there I want them to login and be redirected back to `mydomain.com` which is now my web app. Not the marketing stuff. How do I do that ?

Comment: Well, what should your users see when they're logged in? If it's a dashboard type of a page, maybe you should put that functionality under a different controller.

Comment: It is a dashboard type page. That functionality is in the `home#index` controller.